# Why does the traceback not reference Python files when using a Conda virtual environment?

Tags: python, pandas, conda, rename, traceback

**Summary**

A keyword argument is not found in the pandas *rename* function, since my compiler is using my core Python which has an older version of Pandas even though it should be using my activated Conda environment which has an updated Pandas version with the keyword argument. *I can't figure out why the Traceback is referencing my core Python and Pandas folders instead of the virtual environment.*

**Python**

```
df.rename(columns={
            'COLUMN A':'col_a',
            'COLUMN B':'col_b',},
        inplace=True, errors='raise')
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\Programming\WebApps\testapp\app\main\routes.py", line 52, in upload
    clean_usage_data(df)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\Programming\WebApps\testapp\app\data\move.py", line 94, in clean_usage_data
    inplace=True, errors='raise')
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 197, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4025, in rename
    return super(DataFrame, self).rename(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1072, in rename
    'argument "{0}"'.format(list(kwargs.keys())[0]))
TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "errors"
```

**Error**

Okay so the traceback is pretty straightforward, `errors` is not a kwarg for the pandas dataframe rename method, at least not with the older version that is in my core package, however it is in a [newer version of rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). However, I am using a Conda virtual environment (named "nex_verify") that is activated, with a more updated Pandas package (which has the errors kwarg, which I manually checked for).

I was able to resolve the issue by updating my core pandas package, as expected.

**Question**

Since I am using my Conda environment, why is the Traceback not referring to those folders, but instead the core package folders of pandas?

**Edit**
I tested `sys.executable` with the same result regardless of activating a virtual environment:

```
C:\Users\testuser\Programming\WebApps\testapp>conda activate venv
(venv) C:\Users\testuser\Programming\WebApps\testapp>
```

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\testuser\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
```

Comment: Are you entirely certain that the correct environment is being used? What is the value of `sys.executable` ?

Comment: I added an edit that addresses this.

Comment: Sounds like the **base** environment is prioritized on your `PATH`. Running `conda activate venv` is supposed to handle this. Try checking `PATH` before and after activating. Also, may be worth seeing the baseline `PATH` when no environments are active (`conda deactivate`).

Comment: @merv I checked the path before and after activating the environment with the same result - the path is using the base anaconda files. I have these defined as in the environment user variable "Path"

Comment: Okay, thanks for reply. Not sure I understand what is meant by "*I have these defined...*". Did you explicitly manipulate `PATH` to add the Anaconda3 folder? Anyway, sounds like `conda activate` is not working properly, so basically you need to debug why it is not correctly prepending the **venv** path when running `conda activate venv`.

Comment: @merv yes, I added those environment user variables myself so that I could use command prompt. After some more testing I found that when activating the environment in my command prompt (rather than VSCode), the path was correctly changed to the virtual environment. Previously I was using VSCode, so I think it must be an issue there. Will do some more investigating in VSCode.